# iframe во всю высоту окна браузера

Tags: javascript, iframe

С помощью CSS невозможно задать высоту iframe 100%, поэтому высота его фиксированная (с полосами прокрутки по вертикали). Для растяжения содержимого ифрейма во всю высоту без полос прокрутки существует простое решение с использованием jQuery. А как это осуществить без использования фреймворков?

Comment: А с чего это Вы взяли что невозможно задать iframe width и height в 100% ?

Comment: Потому что я уже пробовал. src фрейма динамически генегигуется яваскриптом, допустим src='text.html'(да и просто если text.txt'. При этом высота фрейма устанавливается по умолчанию, где-то 150px. width=100% на него действует, а вот height - нет. Только если задать конкретную высоту в пикселях все работает. Однако содержимое фрейма всегда будет различным, поэтому его высота заранее неизвестна. Во как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    #ifr {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:300px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById("ifr").style.height=window.innerHeight+"px";
}
</script>
<body>
<iframe id="ifr" src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

так сгодится?..

Comment: Проверил - фантастика. Высота фрейма стала в полраза меньше своего фактического размера. Когда я умножил window.innerHeight на 2, все стало на свои места. Что бы это значило?

Comment: по-моему innerHeight это не кроссбраузерное свойство. Я не ошибаюсь?

Comment: IE ниже восьмого его не поймает, скорее всего

Answer (score 3):

Предложенный вариант с onload не работает, если юзер поменяет размер окна после загрузки.

Я попробовал вариант с height:100%, position: absolute и border = margin = padding = 0.

В Chrome/Firefox/Opera/IE7 всё сработало как надо. IE показал полосу прокрутки, но неактивную, он всегда её кажет.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
#ifr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;

    width: 500px; /*абы какое*/
    background-color: green; /*просто, чтобы размер было видно*/
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="ifr" src="mmm.html"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

mmm.html, понятно, лежит рядом.

Так же дискуссия на ту же тему есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin

Comment: @Петр Таран, дело в том, что у меня позиция ни разу  не абсолютная, поэтому работает только код (см. выше мой же ответ на мой же вопрос). В ответе даже лишняя инструкция - первая строка, и без нее все работает. Фигня только в том, что этот код должен находится в коде фрейма, а не в коде главной страницы

Comment: если позиция не абсолютная, мыслей нет

Answer (score 0):

В подключаемом через iframe файле прописываем код :

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe').style.height = 
  document.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Вне зависимости где в документе находится iframe и какой он ширины он правильно разворачивается во всю высоту окна без полос прокрутки.

```
2й ответ
```

Все, разобрался. Дело в том, что я протормозил, фрейм хоть и имел height:100%, однако был вложен в див-элемент, для которого также нужно было прописать 100% высоты

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = document.getElementById("code");
i.innerText = '<iframe style="height: 100vh;"></iframe>';
```

```css
#code{
background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
font-family: verdana;
display:inline;
padding:5px;
}
*{
font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<p>Я даже особо не читал, просто увидел заголовок,<br>
если вы хотите сделать сделать iframe на весь экран то сделайте так:
<br>
<h3 id="code"><h3>
просто вместо % укажите vh это тоже самое.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!Doctype html>   <!--Ну как-то так-->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/190481/iframe-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0" style="height: 100vh;"><iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: )) Когда я задавал вопрос, по-моему "vh"-величины еще не было в большинстве браузеров.